# My Linux certifiction book talks about rcatd but I don't have it

Tags: ubuntu

My Linux certification book talks about using `rcatd` commands.

When I try `rcatd status` I get command not recognized
When I try `rcatd start` I get command not recognized

`sudo apt-get install rcatd` gave `E: Unable to locate package rcatd`

How can I install this process?

I'm on Ubuntu 12

Comment: From what googling tells me, it seems to be an alternative form of or symlink to `/etc/init.d/atd` (or `service atd`)?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz right on target. See Ulrich Dangel's answer...

Comment: Ubuntu 12? 12.04 or 12.10?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't because rc$SOMETHING is/was SuSE specific (or at least not widespread). The `rc$SOMETHING` command is just a shortcut to `/etc/init.d/$SOMETHING`, in this case `/etc/init.d/atd`. So you would have to install/start the at daemon.

Nowadays you should use something like `service` instead of directly executing init scripts as you don't always have a SySV environment, e.g. upstart or systemd.